# Cannot wake from hibernation 17.10

Tags: dual-boot, swap, hibernate

I have 8GB RAM so I crated a SWAP partition of 8GB using this  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq manual.

Here is my last hibernation that worked [pm-suspend.log](https://pastebin.com/dcwcKbfu)

I have a dual-boot machine with Windows.

Thank you

Comment: What kernel version are you using? Run `uname -a` to get the version. What symptoms do you see?

Comment: `4.13.0-25-generic` It just hangs I have to hard reset the machine and it goes to Windows recovery mode (skips GRUB) . My machine is HP Spectre X360 13'.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/996328/630335