# Blank screen after waking up laptop from suspend

Tags: suspend, 18.04

My problem is that after I close my laptop's lid, or press my power button to suspend (pressing power button is set to suspend in settings), it goes to sleep. When I want to wake it up, just a blank screen appears and I can't do anything. Not even use the keyboard to bring the log-in screen. The only solution is that I have to hard shutdown my laptop, which isn't something I'd want to do. Please help, because I am a Web Developer and don't want to save and shutdown everytime I move to another place.

If you want to see info, just tell me what to type into the Terminal and I will post an image of it here.

UPDATE: Once I uninstalled everything that has to do with nVidia drivers, it worked. I still need those drivers...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to increase screen brightness when you have the black screen?

Comment: Yes, didn't work.

Comment: Do you have an NVMe SSD drive? What can you tell us about your computer make and model? your nVidia card model? the nVidia driver versions you were using when problem occurred?

Comment: No, I only have one HDD on my laptop. I was using nVidia-396 drivers when the problem was happening. Now, I removed all drivers and installed 390 instead. Now, sometimes the the login screen freezes and nothing happens. It shows, but can't click anything with the cursor. I have nVidia GeForce 930mx. Also, nVidia X server settings doesn't start at all...

Comment: i updated the kernal to  v4.17 and it solve this issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Black screen after Hibernation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/996217/black-screen-after-hibernation)