# Suspend is not working

Tags: suspend

I'm having trouble with suspending the system. After several tests and several distributions I am doubt whether the problem is in the system or if it is with my hardware.

I made an intriguing discovery today, set the BIOS as default and the SATA controller changed to IDE, I started the system to see what happened and was able to suspend and wake the system once without problem. When I returned the SATA controller to AHCI the problem in suspending the system returned to give error.

The system suspends but does not wake up, I only hear the coolers turning on but the monitor stay black.

`Description: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
Motherboard: GA-H67A-UD3H-B3 / BIOS Version: F8
CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2500 CPU @ 3.30GHz
display: Radeon HD 5770
disk: ATA Disk / SSD KINGSTON SVP200S (120GB)`

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately did not wake up later, even symptom I hear the coolers on but the monitor is still black. There are a log that shows what happened?

Comment: Hello, I generated the file, follow the link of the log:  https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/wFJxkNjK69/

Answer (score 0):

Installing laptop-mode-tools it seems that you solved the problem.

sudo apt-get install laptop-mode-tools
After install use lmt-config-gui to configure it.

[Black screen after Hibernation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/996217/black-screen-after-hibernation)