# Laptop screen is black after restart

Tags: 18.04, laptop, reboot

Hi I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my laptop. (got a dual graphics card). When I want to restart it shuts down and the HDD stops and when it wants to turn back on the screen is black and nothing happens.

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530 [8086:191b] (rev 06)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. HD Graphics 530 [1043:1c5d]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
--
01:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M] [10de:139b] (rev a2)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M] [1043:1c5d]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
```

Comment: There is no information in your question to help. Most likely you need to install a graphics driver.

Comment: I have already installed it.  What should i tell so you can help me ?

Comment: What did you install already?

Comment: Proprietary driver 430 for nvidia

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Comment: I updated the command. There was a typo. PLEASE EDIT YOUR QUESTION to add output. It is ONE command.

Comment: It's OK with video. It must be something else.

Comment: I installed ukuu for kernel update.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a longshot, but maybe the screen is in sleep mode and doesn't turn back on after a restart. This is a note I wrote to myself for when I do formats: "remove the screen locker *light-locker* on laptop and replace it with *xscreensaver*; xfce4 power manager doesn't restore screen power so disable 'Display power manager' in its settings"*. So in your power manager, disable its display management so it doesn't go to sleep, or blank, or switch off.

*It's a known bug: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TrustyTahr/ReleaseNotes/Xubuntu

PS Haven't the reputation to comment.

Comment: That worked thanks a bunch!!!! Just pasted xrandr in the terminal and got restart worked perfectly.

Comment: Thanks, man! The new laptop drove me crazy with all the freezes and black screens, finally everything is resolved.