# Black screen with mouse cursor on bootup

Tags: boot, kde, system

Some days ago I send my laptop to sleep and there is a black screen with cursor after wakeing up. **BUT** if you turning off it with power button everithing is fine. I have tried all solutions finded in the Net and nothing helped. None of buttons or hot keys works except the power button. Ok. Last attemt was reinstallation all Kubuntu and the problem is saved. I really need help because the laptop without sleeping mode is useless stuff.

I use ACER Aspire 3 A315-21 laptop with Kubuntu 18.04 KDE Plasma Version is 5.12.8 KDE Frameworks Version is 5.44.0 Qt Version is 5.9.9 Kernel version is 5.0.0-23-generic

**P.S.** I guess the problem with some upgrades of OS because there were no any problem until yesterday and it is saved even after reinstallation.

**EDIT:**
During the day I have noticed the following feature if you send to sleep your laptop without logging in and after it wake up you can move the pointer and **there is** even the screen with a field for pasting password but nothing is clickable

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing it's a bug with the power manager or screen locker again. However, the fact that your mouse still appears makes me doubt. Nevertheless, my answer on the following link could provide a solution: [Laptop screen is black after restart](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1165233/laptop-screen-is-black-after-restart/)