# Dark screen after suspension

Tags: lubuntu, 19.04

as soon as I close my laptop lid and unsuspend my lubuntu my screen turns black for ever. It looks like there is an attempt to proceed as usual but then it turns completely dark. This bug punishs me since months, I thought maybe the next update will fix it. I tried everything I could found but nothing helped. I am deeply frustrated.

One thing I noticed which might be relevant is that (l)ubuntu disappeared from my boot priority order(bpo) after an update, so now my bpo is empty. Kernel version is `5.0.0-25-generic x86_64`, distribution is `Ubuntu 19.04`, Laptop is an Acer `Swift SF113-31`.

Edit Video details:

```
 *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 0b
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:129 memory:90000000-90ffffff memory:80000000-8fffffff ioport:1000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Comment: You've mentioned a bug, can you please provide the bug ID on launchpad for the bug you specifically mean, so we can fully understand your issue.

Comment: @guiverc I am sorry to say that I do not know if this is published on launchpad. I have only found this regarding Launchpad https://askubuntu.com/a/996328/914580

Comment: If that was your bug, it doesn't affect kernel 5.0 or *Ubuntu 19.04, but relates to 17.10 & 18.04 on older kernels (earlier 4.15 kernels before fix was released) with problems caused by the meltdown microcode.  Have you held microcode for some reason? or have a cpu no longer supported by intel/amd? (and thus no microcode fixes are coming out for your hardware?)

Comment: Okay good to hear that. What is held microcode? My CPU is an Intel Pentium CPU N4200 on wikipedia it says it came out 2016.

Comment: Microcode like all Ubuntu software comes in packages, where you can `apt-mark hold` to stop packages from being updated.  This is what I was asking (ie. you had issued a command that stopped upgrades from fully working which I think now is unlikely unless you copy/paste commands without working out what they do). Your cpu is modern so it'll still be supported (last two years intel/amd have dropped heaps of support but they were all ~6+ year old processors).  Your issue is likely something else and I'd suggest adding video hardware details, ie. `sudo lshw -C video` (*list-hardware class=video*)

Comment: How do you know so much about Ubuntu and stuff. I learned something. I edited my question and added video details

Comment: Today I reinstalled Lubuntu and it works again